# osmdroid offline - ZIP size limitation?

Tags: android, zip, osmdroid

do you know any ZIP file, for offline osmdroid use, limitations? I have 23MB Zip file with maps, but I am not able to find out, why my maps aren't displayed? In this ZIP file I have 23000 files (limit for ZIP is 65535), so I don't see any problem here.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Try using GEMF format instead of ZIP for static map data.  the format was designed for efficent decoding on resource imited platforms like Android.  If you are using Mobile Atlas Creator just choose the GEMF format and copy the file like you would a zip file.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, there is no specific limitation but the file system limitations. But opening a big zip file to search for tiles is time and resource consuming and in small devices with limited resources may cause OutOfMemoryException.

When I unzipped file and renamed all tiles as z/x/y.tile, the speed increased at least 10 times!

I strongly recommend using no zip file.