# Tiles are only for some zoom levels available

Tags: android, osmdroid

I faced the problem that my map tiles are only shown for zoom levels 14 to 17
I am using offline Mapnik maps. The tiles are in the correct folder (/osmdroid/Mapnik.zip) and  in the correct format (.png).

Im starting at zoom 16. when zooming in to 17 there is no problem but when zooming to 18 only the tiles of 17 are scaled.  and if I zoom out for a while the tiles for the zoom levels 1-14 not shown. There is only a grey box.

The pngs for these zoom levels are in the .zip archive :/ so i dont know what to do. Does someone have an idea ?

My code is like that:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public static final GeoPoint INITIAL_POSITION = new GeoPoint(48.965558, 9.27893);
MapView mapView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(16);
    mapView.getController().setCenter(INITIAL_POSITION);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved the Problem by splitting into 4 zip files :D

The problem was 150000 files in one zip archive is to big to handle...

See [Too much Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870436/osmdroid-offline-zip-size-limitation) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Osmdroid does not support zooming past the zoom levels that you actually downloaded. What you see exactly corresponds to that.

If you want to view the map on other zoom levels you simply must download them (prepare offline version) or turn the use of data connection on (`setUseDataConnection(true);`) but of course the tiles not in the offline version won't appear if you don't have the data connection.

You could alternatively modify `TilesOverlay` class of osmdroid but that *won't* be easy and will take time.

Comment: I cant use offline tiles without a data conection ?? The tablet on wich the app have to work does not support a internet connection.. You say i cant zoom out but when I start in zoomlevel 1 there is a grey block,too and I have the coresponding maptiles in the zip archive :(

Comment: yes you can! but you must have tiles for all zoom levels that you want the user to be able to view. for example if your archive contains tiles for zoom levels 6 to 17, user won't be able to view the map at zoom level *below 6* and *above 17*.

Comment: ok but I have all Tiles from 1 to 18 in my zip archive and I only can see 14 to 17

Comment: oh, I assumed you have only the 14-17 zoom levels. sorry for that. in that case, if you have sources of osmdroid and don't just use the library, you can set `OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.DEBUGMODE` to `true` and post LogCat output. it will then report load operation of every tile.

Comment: Im using the lib only :( can u upload a jar with debugmode set, or are there other ways to debug :/ ?

Comment: I would suggest getting the sources from osmdroid project site and pastring them under your `src` directory. You can then change mentioned flag to `true` and debug everything as needed.

Comment: Are there Size limitations on the zip files ? Because my primary archive file is about 800MB :/

Comment: @MatthiasH oringal ZIP format has a limitation of 2 or 4GB on the whole zip file. Also the total number of entries in orignal format is capped by `256 * 256 - 1 = 65535`. But as always it also depends on the particular implementation. So I guess you may be exceeding this limit and using legacy reading implementation for which mentioned limitations apply.